# Create DNS query with Netcat or /dev/udp/

Tags: linux, bash, debian, command-line, dns

I'm trying to send a valid DNS request with either `nc` or `bash` and `/dev/udp/`.

I created a valid DNS packet to use as a template:

```
tcpdump -XX port 53
```

Then, in a new terminal made a request with curl:

```
curl https://duckduckgo.com/
```

This generates the following data in the tcpdump terminal.

```
    0x0000:  4500 003c b0b4 4000 4011 73c3 0a00 020f  E..<..@.@.s.....
    0x0010:  0a2a 0001 bdd4 0035 0028 4f24 cfc9 0100  .*.....5.(O$....
    0x0020:  0001 0000 0000 0000 0a64 7563 6b64 7563  .........duckduc
    0x0030:  6b67 6f03 636f 6d00 0001 0001            kgo.com.....
```

From this, I modified the request slightly to match [this reference](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=170369) and saved it to a file `/tmp/ddg.txt`.

```
0000:  4500 003c b0b4 4000 4011 73c3 0a00 020f  E..<..@.@.s.....
0010:  0a2a 0001 bdd4 0035 0028 4f24 cfc9 0100  .*.....5.(O$....
0020:  0001 0000 0000 0000 0a64 7563 6b64 7563  .........duckduc
0030:  6b67 6f03 636f 6d00 0001 0001            kgo.com.....
```

Then, tried generating a request, but I get the following error message:

```
xxd -r /tmp/ddg.txt | nc -q 1 -nu 10.42.0.1 53
xxd: sorry, cannot seek backwards.
```

In Wireshark, the request appears malformed. What am I getting wrong here? It is possible to send a proper DNS query with this method?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have used *tcpdump*. But you should then have used *wireshark* the same way you did later: you would have seen that you made the same mistake as in the link you provided: you included the extra [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header)+[UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#UDP_datagram_structure) headers: you must only provide the UDP payload to the *netcat* command, since it sends an IPv4 UDP packet already.

Here's the data in hex without any superfluous addresses:

[IPv4 header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header):

```
4500 003c b0b4 4000 4011 73c3 0a00 020f 0a2a 0001
```

[UDP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#UDP_datagram_structure) (the 0028 is the length of the whole UDP part: 8+20 => payload of length 0x20 = 32 bytes):

```
bdd4 0035 0028 4f24
```

UDP payload:

```
cfc9 0100 0001 0000 0000 0000 0a64 7563 6b64 7563 6b67 6f03 636f 6d00 0001 0001
```

`xxd` can use the `-p` parameter and not write but more importantly not need any address with `-r` (which avoids having to rewrite and now renumber those addresses):

> `-p | -ps | -postscript | -plain`
> Output in postscript continuous hexdump style. Also known as plain hexdump style.

When reversed (`-r`) it will also ignore any white spaces wherever they are.

Here's a test done (I just put back your own DNS server IP instead of the test one which worked fine):

```
$ echo cfc9 0100 0001 0000 0000 0000 0a64 7563 6b64 7563 6b67 6f03 636f 6d00 0001 0001 |
    xxd -p -r | nc -q1 -w2 -n -u 10.42.0.1 53 | xxd
00000000: cfc9 8180 0001 0001 0004 0000 0a64 7563  .............duc
00000010: 6b64 7563 6b67 6f03 636f 6d00 0001 0001  kduckgo.com.....
00000020: c00c 0001 0001 0000 005e 0004 2872 b19c  .........^..(r..
00000030: c00c 0002 0001 0002 91bb 0014 0464 6e73  .............dns
00000040: 3303 7030 3505 6e73 6f6e 6503 6e65 7400  3.p05.nsone.net.
00000050: c00c 0002 0001 0002 91bb 0007 0464 6e73  .............dns
00000060: 31c0 41c0 0c00 0200 0100 0291 bb00 0704  1.A.............
00000070: 646e 7332 c041 c00c 0002 0001 0002 91bb  dns2.A..........
00000080: 0007 0464 6e73 34c0 41                   ...dns4.A
```

Replacing *netcat* with *socat*: replace `nc -q1 -w2 -n -u 10.42.0.1 53` with `socat udp4:10.42.0.1:53 -`. It deals better with EOF conditions (so no need to wait two seconds).

---

If you want to use bash's built-in `/dev/udp` instead of *netcat* or *socat* then it becomes a bit more complicated to handle a full-duplex socket with two half-duplex commands (one only writes, the other only reads). For this non-interactive case, no need to fork the first output command (else, for more complex cases, the `;` before `dd` can be replaced with `&` to have output and input working in parallel). It still requires `dd` in order to grab only one packet and finish, thus avoiding `xxd` blocking:

```
( echo cfc9 0100 0001 0000 0000 0000 0a64 7563 6b64 7563 6b67 6f03 636f 6d00 0001 0001 | xxd -p -r >&3; dd bs=9000 count=1 <&3 2>/dev/null | xxd ) 3>/dev/udp/10.42.0.1/53
```